# Trouble with one of my constrains

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I'm having some troubles with one my constrains in code
This the error i'm getting

```
2017-04-08 18:14:36.798 App[465:89996] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.   ("<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x16eb9f00 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x16d0cb40(64)]>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x16eb2de0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x16d0cb40]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x16d32990 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16d06120 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x16d0cb40]-(0)-[UITableView:0x17ba6e00]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16f45f90 V:|-(63.2)-[UITableView:0x17ba6e00]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x16d32990 )>"  ) Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
```

This is the code that i have for the constrain:
Viewdidload

```
let aka = (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)! + 19.2
holamama = tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: aka)

//This is out of any methods...
var holamama = NSLayoutConstraint()
```

In my UIBUtton:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([holamama])
```

Other UIButton:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([holamama])
```

So what can i do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved doing this: 
First, i connected an IBOutlet of my tableview's top constrain

```
@IBOutlet var constrainTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then, when i press the button, this happen:

```
let aka = (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)! + 1.0
constrainTop.constant = aka
```

And when i press the other button, this happen:

```
constrainTop.constant = 0
```

I just had to modified the constant of my tableView

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't specified the behavior you want, I can't suggest a better way to do it. However, I can help explain what's going wrong.

The error message is pretty helpful in this case. It lists four constraints, suggesting that at least one is erroneous.

```
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x16eb9f00 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x16d0cb40(64)]>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x16eb2de0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x16d0cb40]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x16d32990 )>",
```

These two constraints are of type `_UILayoutSupportConstraint`, which means in this case that you didn't create them. Together they define the position of the `topLayoutGuide`. Thus, they are likely not the problem.

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16d06120 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x16d0cb40]-(0)-[UITableView:0x17ba6e00]>",
```

This constraint says "the top of the of the `UITableView` is touching the bottom of the `_UILayoutGuide`.

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16f45f90 V:|-(63.2)-[UITableView:0x17ba6e00]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x16d32990 )>"
```

This is your explicitly created constraint. It says "the top of the `UITableView` is 63.2 points below the top of its superview.

Do you see why Auto Layout is complaining? You're telling it that the top of the `UITableView` must touching the bottom of the `_UILayoutGuide`, 64 points below the top of the screen, *and must also* be 63.2 points below the top of the screen. Those two demands are incompatible, hence the error.

Comment: I want to, when i press i button, activate that constrain. So when i press the button, the constrain of the tableview's top change and have a constant of, in this case, 19.2